# How to add Image to Mail

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox, mailmessage

In my application,I am sending mail using C#, now want to insert image in mail like does.
I am passing HTML body,in mail body.
So how can i insert image at run time at any position and Receiver can receive mail as mail sent.
I am converting RichtextBox String into HTML at Send Button means at the time of sending mail.

The Current Problem is I am able to set Image in RichtextBox but I can't get RichTextbox when converting String To HTML from RichtextBox

Comment: Previously i have tried to get position of Image in String and at time of sending mail, I was just putting Image tag and done..But now i am Formating String Like Bold So my String will Converted At Sending time In HTMl so my idea to track position of Image not working

Answer (score 0):

```
RichTextBox rtb;

Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph();
InlineUIContainer uiContainer = new InlineUIContainer();
uiContainer.Child = new Image(); //Create and add your image here
paragraph.Inlines.Add(uiContainer);
rtb.Document.Blocks.Add(paragraph);
```

Comment: Currently I am doing this for GUI but what to do to send this image with appropriate place in message body for sending mail